# 4 nitro groups on benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, phenols, nitro-compounds, steric-effects

I was just wondering if there exists a phenol having 4 nitro groups. I tried searching the internet but couldn't find anything. If it exists what all features should it possess, and will it be more acidic than a trinitrophenol?

Comment: Even 5 is possible.

Comment: PubChem's records about [tetranitrophenol](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=tetranitrophenol), and the one about [pentanitrophenol](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=pentanitrophenol).

Comment: @Buttonwood Thank you sir.Got a great web to check all compounds which come to mind but I don't come across in my book

Comment: I would not like to try to isolate it

Comment: They "exist" but not much more then that. And are weaker acids, because of SIR.

Comment: You might find Derek Lowe's article, *Can't Stop the Nitro Groups*, https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/can-t-stop-nitro-groups, enlightening (and entertaining) -- you might get a real bang out of it.